# Не работает код с IF в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

у меня есть список, делаю с списком массив и сортирую

```
st="ман ба мактаб меравам"
arr=st.split()
print(arr)
a=sorted(arr, key=len)
print(a)
```

использую этот код, хочу использовать If для сортировки по asc и desc, сделал таким образом но не работает помогите пожалуйста, я п Python новичок не судите строга)

```
st="ман ба мактаб меравам"
arr=st.split()
print(arr)
print('Как вы хотите сортировать?')
print(' [1] - ASC ')
print(' [2] - DESC ')
do=input('Выбрать номер действия: ')

if do == 1:
    a=sorted(arr, key=len)
    print(a)
if do == 2:
    pass
```

и как мне сортировать по убыванию?

Comment: У вас ещё и сравнение неправильное, в `do` у вас строка, а вы сравниваете в `if` с целыми числами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у `sorted` есть параметр `reverse` его надо поставить `True`

```
sorted(arr, key=len, reverse = True)
```

а также у вас в `do` хранится строка а не число

```
do = int(input('Выбрать номер действия: '))
```